# Custom EventHandler for a button

Tags: c#, button

I want to assign a custom event handler to a button.

I made an event handler as under

```
public class ButtonEventHandler
{
    ButtonEventHandler()
    {
        // Assign a function to delegate
        this.ClickHandler = _ClickHandler;
    }

    public delegate void ClickHandlerDelegate(object sender, EventArgs e);
    public ClickHandlerDelegate ClickHandler;
    private void _ClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

I then assigned it to the Button, inside the constructor of another class

```
public ImgButton(Image image, string lblTxt, ButtonEventHandler eventHandler)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.lblTxt.Click      += eventHandler.ClickHandler;
}
```

When I try to compile, I get below error

> **Error** Cannot implicitly convert type 'ClickHandlerDelegate' to
>   'System.EventHandler'

**What to do ? Can delegates be inherited ? If yes, how ? if not, then how to explicitly convert ?**

Answer (score 1):

You dont need create delegate object, just create method as public and handle it to click event

```
public class ButtonEventHandler
{    
    public void ClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Also you can create it as static if don't want to create instance object

Comment: I need a delegate as I want to eventually use different methods for different type of buttons... which would be decided at the time of creating buttons.

Comment: It works after I declare the type of the `ClickHandler` as `System.EventHandler` instead of `ClickHandlerDelegate`

Comment: Ofcourse it's working coz expecting System.EventHandler, but still you can use the method instead of delegate object. Delegate object is method's pointer, so you can use method directly if following correct signiture

Comment: In that case, I would use method as `myButton.Click += ButtonEventHandler.ClickHandler` Right ?

Comment: Yes, but if you want to use like that you should create ClickHandler as a Static. If you don't want to have static method so you should use create instance object from ButtonEventHandler